# Trace incoming multicast UDP messages with Wireshark

Tags: networking, udp, wireshark, multicast, tshark

I have an application `A` that is sending a multicast message to application `B`

The log shows the following:

```
Sender: 48704 -> /239.6.7.8:46655
Receiver: /172.17.95.17:48704, Hello, world!
Sender: 48704 -> /239.6.7.8:46655
Receiver: /172.17.95.17:48704, Hello, world!
Sender: 48704 -> /239.6.7.8:46655
Receiver: /172.17.95.17:48704, Hello, world!
```

As you can see, I am able to connect, send and receive messages.

In `tshark`, I can see only what the sender is sending.

What do I need to do in order to see the incoming message?

```
[hudson@edg-perf09 ~]$ tshark -ni any | grep "46655"
Capturing on 'any'
0.114114866 172.17.95.17 -> 239.6.7.8    UDP 57 Source port: 48704  Destination port: 46655
1.115497174 172.17.95.17 -> 239.6.7.8    UDP 57 Source port: 48704  Destination port: 46655
2.116822371 172.17.95.17 -> 239.6.7.8    UDP 57 Source port: 48704  Destination port: 46655
3.118153942 172.17.95.17 -> 239.6.7.8    UDP 57 Source port: 48704  Destination port: 46655
4.119370365 172.17.95.17 -> 239.6.7.8    UDP 57 Source port: 48704  Destination port: 46655
5.120568524 172.17.95.17 -> 239.6.7.8    UDP 57 Source port: 48704  Destination port: 46655
6.121715504 172.17.95.17 -> 239.6.7.8    UDP 57 Source port: 48704  Destination port: 46655
```

Comment: Application A is sending to a Reserved multicast group, and it is not allowed to use that group. It should either register a multicast group with IANA or it should use a group in the Organization-local scope (`239.0.0.0/8`).

Comment: Change your filter to look for the IP of the multicast sender

Comment: @RonMaupin Thaks for the feedback about changing it to `239.0.0.0/8`. I set it to `239.6.7.8` but I still can see only what the sender is sending in Wireshark

Comment: @dbush using the filter `udp` didn't show the incoming request.

Comment: Does the sender have multiple interfaces?  Is it possible it's sending multicast on one interface and receiving unicast on another?

Comment: @dush I tried to capture in any interface. I updated the question addressing all your questions. Thanks for the feedback.